# “How to fix ‘ForeignKey’ error in Laravel”

Tags: laravel

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Yo
>   u have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your Ma
>   riaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete CASCADE' at l
>   ine 1")

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452
```

> PDO::prepare("alter table `pengerjaan` add constraint `pengerjaan_id_kateg
>   ori_foreign` foreign key (`id_kategori`) references `kategori` () on delete CASC
>   ADE")

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:452

public function up(){
     Schema::create('pengerjaan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedinteger('id_kategori');
            $table->unsignedinteger('id_pelanggan');
            $table->enum('status', array('proses', 'pending', 'hasil'));
            $table->datetime('apply_date');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('id_kategori')->refrences('id')->on('kategori')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('id_pelanggan')->refrences('id')->on('pelanggan')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('pengerjaan');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error, it is not `refrences` but it is `references` so change this two lines:

```
$table->foreign('id_kategori')->refrences('id')->on('kategori')->onDelete('CASCADE');
$table->foreign('id_pelanggan')->refrences('id')->on('pelanggan')->onDelete('CASCADE');
```

with this:

```
$table->foreign('id_kategori')->references('id')->on('kategori')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('id_pelanggan')->references('id')->on('pelanggan')->onDelete('cascade');
```